# a 8086 assembly language program to calculate the average of any n sum of numbers

Tags: assembly, masm

How do I write an 8086 assembly language program to calculate the average of any `n` numbers? I wrote two programs. One uses the `mov ah,01 int 21h` input function and so it only accepts one number. For this reason I cannot input a number like 10.

I read from a buffer in the other one. It can accept a lot of digits, but the problem is that it loops continuously.

Here is the first program:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
        VAL1    DB      ?
        NL1     DB      0AH,0DH,'ENTER HOW MANY NO U WANT:','$'
        NL2     DB      0AH,0DH,'ENTER NO:','$'
        NL3     DB      0AH,0DH,'AVEARGE:','$'
.CODE
MAIN    PROC
        MOV AX,@DATA
        MOV DS,AX

        LEA DX,NL1
        MOV AH,09H
        INT 21H

        MOV AH,01H
        INT 21H
        SUB AL,30H

        MOV CL,AL
        MOV BL,AL
        MOV AL,00
        MOV VAL1,AL

LBL1:
        LEA DX,NL2
        MOV AH,09H
        INT 21H

        MOV AH,01H
        INT 21H
        SUB AL,30H

        ADD AL,VAL1
        MOV VAL1,AL
        LOOP LBL1

LBL2:
        LEA DX,NL3
        MOV AH,09H
        INT 21H

        MOV AX,00
        MOV AL,VAL1
        DIV BL
        ADD AX,3030H
        MOV DX,AX
        MOV AH,02H
        INT 21H

        MOV AH,4CH
        INT 21H

MAIN    ENDP
        END     MAIN
```

and here is the second:

```
TITLE "THIS PROGRAM CALCULATES ANY N NUMBER OF STUDENT AVERAGE SCORES"

.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
        VAL1         DB      ?
        DISPLAY1     DB      0AH,0DH,'HOW MANY NUMBER OF STUDENT SCORES DO YOU WANT TO INPUT? :','$'
        DISPLAY2         DB      0AH,0DH,'ENTER NO:','$'
        DISPLAY3         DB      0AH,0DH,'AVEARGE:','$'
    BUFFER       DB      3,4 DUP(?)
.CODE
MAIN    PROC

.STARTUP

        LEA DX,DISPLAY1 ; loads the message in the variable display 1
        MOV AH,09H  ; interrupt function to display the message
        INT 21H

        MOV AH,0AH  ; Read into buffer
    INT 21H
    SUB AL,30H

    MOV CL,AL
    MOV BL,AL   ; moves the content of al to bl register
        MOV AL,00   ; sets the value of al to zero, the value of al is now in bl register
        MOV VAL1,AL ; stores al in val1 NB: al is still zero.

LBL1:
        LEA DX,DISPLAY2 ; displays message in display 2
        MOV AH,09H
        INT 21H

        MOV AH,0AH  ;Read into buffer
    LEA DX,BUFFER
    INT 21H
    SUB AL,30H

        ADD AL,VAL1 ; add val1 to al i.e, it now adds the previous value to the new one.
        MOV VAL1,AL ; saves the added value to val 1.
        LOOP LBL1   ; continues too add.

LBL2:
        LEA DX,DISPLAY3 ; displays character in display 3
        MOV AH,09H
        INT 21H

        MOV AX,00   ; sets ax value back to 00
        MOV AL,VAL1 ; moves the total value back to al
        DIV BL      ; divides the total value with the inputed number of values tht was stored in bl
        ADD AX,3030H    ;  convert to ASCII
        MOV DX,AX   ; now moves the content of ax register to data register
        MOV AH,09H  ; this displays the result
        INT 21H

.EXIT

MAIN    ENDP
        END     MAIN
```

Comment: Isn't it obvious that you are not exiting the loop in LBL1 ?

Comment: please how do i do that?

Comment: The `loop` instruction will use `cx` as a counter (at least I'm pretty sure this was the case for 8086; I'm extrapolating from this being the behavior with `ecx` on 80386 and later models).  I see you modify `cl`, but not `ch` or `cx` itself, so `LBL1` could loop for quite a while, depending on what value was in `cx` when your program started.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be having an "issue" with `int 21h/0Ah`. The first time you do it, you don't set `dx` to any sensible buffer. Your input will be scribbling on your prompt (probably doesn't do much harm). Inside your loop, you do set `dx` to a correct buffer. But when `int 21h/0Ah` returns, you're using `al` as if it were useful (both times). It's been a long time since I did dos, but my recollection is that `al` will be the last character entered - almost certainly the "enter" key - 13 or 0Dh I think.

When `int 21h/0Ah` returns, the second byte in your buffer (`buffer + 1`) will be the number of characters entered. As I recall, this will include the "enter" key. You probably want to check this value to see how many characters you need to "convert" to numbers. The characters entered (1 or 2) will start at `buffer + 2`. Those are the characters you want to convert to a number - first character -'0' times 10 + second character -'0'. Or just character -'0' if there's only one.

When you attempt to print the result, you're okay through `add ax, 3030h`. Then you move this value to `dx`. `int 21h/9` expects a pointer to a $-terminated string in `dx`. This isn't what you've got! Either move those two characters to a buffer and terminate it with a '$', or print 'em one at a time... I used to like that hokey `int 29h`, but you're probably better off to use something that'll print so stdout (`int 29h` goes to the screen and can't be redirected). Maybe something like...

```
...
add ax, 3030h
mov dx, ax
mov ah, 2
xchg dl, dh ; print dh first, then dl
int 21h
xchg dl, dh
int 21h ; I think ah is still okay here...
...
```

Before entering your loop at `LBL1:`, you set `cl` to... something (I don't think it's right). `ch` is "probably" xero, but I'd make sure!

That's all untested, "from memory"... and I may not remember right, but it should get you a little closer (I hope)...

Answer (score -3):

```
DATA SEGMENT 
  ONENO DW 04h
  SECONDNO DW 08h
  SUM DB 00h
  AVG DB 00h
ENDS    
CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME DS:DATA CS:CODE
    START:
        MOV AX,DATA
        MOV DS,AX
        MOV AX,00
        MOV AX,ONENO
        ADD AX,SECONDNO
        MOV SUM,AL
        MOV BL,02
        DIV BL
        MOV AVG,AL
     CODE ENDS
END START
```